# Kotlin: High-Performance concurrent file I/O best-practices?

Tags: performance, kotlin, concurrency, io, jvm

What's the most performant way in Kotlin to allow concurrent file I/O in multi-reader, single-writer fashion?

I have the below, but I'm unsure how much overhead is being created by the coroutine facilities:

- `AsyncFileChannel`, with extension functions to use it in a `suspend` context

  - Taken from example here: https://github.com/Kotlin/coroutines-examples/blob/master/examples/io/io.kt
- `DiskManager` class, that uses a custom `ReadWriteMutex`

Searching for examples of this doesn't turn up much (try searching Github for `ReadWriteMutex`, there are a tiny handful of Kotlin repos implementing this).

```kotlin
class DiskManagerImpl(file: File) : DiskManager {
    private val mutex = ReadWriteMutexImpl()
    private val channel = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(file.toPath(),
        StandardOpenOption.READ, StandardOpenOption.WRITE)

    override suspend fun readPage(pageId: PageId, buffer: MemorySegment) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        mutex.withReadLock {
            val offset = pageId * PAGE_SIZE
            val bytesRead = channel.readAsync(buffer.asByteBuffer(), offset.toLong())
            require(bytesRead == PAGE_SIZE) { "Failed to read page $pageId" }
        }
    }

    override suspend fun writePage(pageId: PageId, buffer: MemorySegment) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        mutex.withWriteLock {
            val offset = pageId * PAGE_SIZE
            val bytesWritten = channel.writeAsync(buffer.asByteBuffer(), offset.toLong())
            require(bytesWritten == PAGE_SIZE) { "Failed to write page $pageId" }
        }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
class ReadWriteMutexImpl : ReadWriteMutex {
    private val read = Mutex()
    private val write = Mutex()
    private val readers = atomic(0)

    override suspend fun lockRead() {
        if (readers.getAndIncrement() == 0) {
            read.lock()
        }
    }

    override fun unlockRead() {
        if (readers.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
            read.unlock()
        }
    }

    override suspend fun lockWrite() {
        read.lock()
        write.lock()
    }

    override fun unlockWrite() {
        write.unlock()
        read.unlock()
    }
}

suspend inline fun <T> ReadWriteMutex.withReadLock(block: () -> T): T {
    lockRead()
    return try {
        block()
    } finally {
        unlockRead()
    }
}

suspend inline fun <T> ReadWriteMutex.withWriteLock(block: () -> T): T {
    lockWrite()
    return try {
        block()
    } finally {
        unlockWrite()
    }
}
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but I'm not sure if it makes sense to use `AsynchronousFileChannel` with coroutines. AFAIK operating systems don't support non-blocking IO for files, so `AsynchronousFileChannel` does a pretty much the same thing as `Dispatchers.IO` - it delegates blocking IO into the special pool of threads. Instead of `channel.readAsync()` you can just block. If you keep existing code then `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` is not needed. You can invoke suspend functions from any dispatcher, `Dispatchers.IO` is for blocking code which you don't have here.

Comment: Also, I think there is no simple answer to what is the best / most-performant solution. It really depends on the specific case. For example, your solution highly favor readers. Readers and writers are not handled in FIFO, as long as there is at least a single reader, writers have to wait. Worst case scenario is that writers will never write. One of the most performant ways to handle multi-readers and multi-writers is to only append, but that requires changing the approach entirely. So it really depends on a specific case.

Comment: Ah that is solid advice, thanks a lot! Also, about the general concept of async file IO: Linux has AIO + io_uring, and it's a bit obscure but Windows has a flagged called "FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED" for async. When you create AsyncFileChannel this flag is set (https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/6765f902505fbdd02f25b599f942437cd805cad1/src/java.base/windows/classes/sun/nio/fs/WindowsChannelFactory.java#L192-L193)

Comment: > "Readers and writers are not handled in FIFO, as long as there is at least a single reader, writers have to wait. " Ah snap, you don't say? That won't work at all -- this is meant to be used for a SQL database buffer pool where there are always concurrent reads

Comment: Ok, maybe I'm wrong and `AsynchronousFileChannel` can use true non-blocking depending on the platform. Documentations says: "An AsynchronousFileChannel is associated with a thread pool to which tasks are submitted to handle I/O events", but maybe I read it wrong or this is the default behavior and it could be optimized. And for FIFO: at least this is what I see in your code. Readers are always let-in if we are already in the read mode. THey only increment/decrement the counter, so they can do this for any amount of time.

Comment: Do you plan to scan through a file from start to end or are you seeking randomly?

Comment: It would be random access reads and writes, always the same size (4096 bytes) and in increments of 4096